# How to make an enemy stop and start movement in a tower defence game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, tags, boolean

I'm making a tower defence game (followed from Brackeys tutorials) and I want to make it so that when the enemies hit an obstacle or and enemy infront, that they stop. When the obstacle or enemy infront is destroyed I want them to move forward again.

I'm using node based transportation for these enemies, from the Brackeys tutorial. It's been super helpful so far, and I'm at a poitn where I want to add extra things into the game.

Just to clarify, the enemies do stop when they encounter an obstacle or other enemy, they just won't move again after. The enemies also have a rigidbody so they can detect triggers, and obstacles and enemies both have a trigger collider on them.

Here is all of the Enemy Movement Code:

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Enemy))]
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform target;
    private int wavepointIndex = 0;

    EnemyTurret eTurret;

    private Enemy enemy;

    public bool canMove = true;


    //private CapsuleCollider _cc;
    

    private void Start()
    {
        enemy = GetComponent<Enemy>();

        target = WaypointScript.points[0];
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("Obstacle") || col.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            canMove = false;

            Debug.Log("Stop");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("Obstacle") || col.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            if (col.GetComponent<Enemy>().health <= 0)
            {
                Movement();
                Debug.Log("Start Moving!");
            }            
        }
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        canMove = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (canMove == true)
        {
            Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
            transform.Translate(dir.normalized * enemy.speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) <= 0.4f)
            {
                GetNextWayPoint();
            }

            enemy.speed = enemy.startSpeed;
        }        
    }

    void GetNextWayPoint() //Sets the new waypoint to the enemy, however when it finishes it's cycle of waypoints, the enemy is destroyed.
    {
        if (wavepointIndex >= WaypointScript.points.Length - 1)
        {
            EndPath();
            return;
        }

        wavepointIndex++;
        target = WaypointScript.points[wavepointIndex];
    }

    void EndPath()
    {
        canMove = false;

        //PlayerStats.Health--;
        //Destroy(gameObject);
    } ```
````

Comment: could it be that you are destroying the enemy collider once the enemies health reaches 0 and so the code in the second conditional statement in OnTriggerStay isn't executed?

Comment: @Sam as in disabling it? so that it can stop another time, maybe with a small delay so that there is a gap between enemies again?

Comment: You are likely destroying the enemy that reached 0 health before the current one has time to start moving again. The code isn’t complete though, there’s still some enemy and obstacle code missing. What happens to an enemy when it reaches 0 health?

Comment: but yeah, you can try that. Sorry I thought you didn’t understand my question

Comment: When an enemy reaches 0 health it is destroyed. Should I do something before it gets destroyed?

Comment: A quick fix would be to add a short delay before the enemy is destroyed. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html here you can see that you can add a delay in the destroy method itself.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot you could add a delay to this.

Comment: If your problem was solved, I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just converting my comments into an answer so you can accept it if you've solved your issue.

Could it be that you are destroying the enemy collider once the enemies health reaches 0 and so the code in the second conditional statement in OnTriggerStay isn't executed?

A quick fix would be to add a short delay before the enemy is destroyed. [Here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) you can see that you can add a delay in the destroy method itself.

Comment: Well in that case you really have to provide more information in your question. Add all the code necessary to form a complete picture and then someone may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The enemy or obstacle is probably destroyed before the *OnTriggerStay()* function can check it's health. You can try storing the enemy or obstacle in a **GameObject** object and then in *Update()* enable movement when the object returns to null because it is destroyed.

You can also try using *OnTriggerExit()* like this:

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("Obstacle") || col.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Movement();
            Debug.Log("Start Moving!");           
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean above the code. I also tried the code and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Just checked the text above cause I'm a moron, however this doesn't work. I think because the collider is in the centre of the enemy, each enemy is going into two colliders (infron and behind).